# Project Euler 19. Too many Sundays

Tags: python

From Euler:
*1 Jan 1900 was a Monday.  How many Sundays fell on the first of the month during the twentieth century (1 Jan 1901 to 31 Dec 2000)?*

My first function collects every day into a list starting from the known Monday and ending on Dec 31, 2000.  The second function saves every seven days into a list of Sundays beginning with the first Sunday in 1901.

```
def dayListBuild():
    dayListBuild = [[0,0,0]]
    for year in range(1900, 2001):
        for month in range(1, 13):
            if month in [4, 6, 9, 11]:
                dayRange = 30
            elif not month - 2:
                if year % 4 and (not year % 100 or year % 400):
                        dayRange = 29
                else:
                    dayRange = 28
            else:
                dayRange = 31
            for day in range(1, dayRange + 1):
                dayListBuild.append([year, month, day])
    return dayListBuild

def sundayList():
    dayList = dayListBuild()
    sundayList = []
    for day in range(len(dayList)):
        if not (day - 6) % 7 and dayList[day][0] > 1900 and not dayList[day][2] - 1:
            sundayList.append(dayList[day])
    return len(sundayList)

print(sundayList())
```

Output: 200.
My answer is off by 29.  The required answer is 171.
This is my list of Sundays:

```
[[1901, 3, 1], [1901, 11, 1], [1902, 5, 1], [1903, 1, 1], [1903, 4, 1], [1903, 7, 1], [1904, 9, 1], [1904, 12, 1], [1905, 3, 1], [1905, 11, 1], [1906, 5, 1], [1907, 1, 1], [1907, 4, 1], [1907, 7, 1], [1908, 9, 1], [1908, 12, 1], [1909, 3, 1], [1909, 11, 1], [1910, 5, 1], [1911, 1, 1], [1911, 4, 1], [1911, 7, 1], [1912, 9, 1], [1912, 12, 1], [1913, 3, 1], [1913, 11, 1], [1914, 5, 1], [1915, 1, 1], [1915, 4, 1], [1915, 7, 1], [1916, 9, 1], [1916, 12, 1], [1917, 3, 1], [1917, 11, 1], [1918, 5, 1], [1919, 1, 1], [1919, 4, 1], [1919, 7, 1], [1920, 9, 1], [1920, 12, 1], [1921, 3, 1], [1921, 11, 1], [1922, 5, 1], [1923, 1, 1], [1923, 4, 1], [1923, 7, 1], [1924, 9, 1], [1924, 12, 1], [1925, 3, 1], [1925, 11, 1], [1926, 5, 1], [1927, 1, 1], [1927, 4, 1], [1927, 7, 1], [1928, 9, 1], [1928, 12, 1], [1929, 3, 1], [1929, 11, 1], [1930, 5, 1], [1931, 1, 1], [1931, 4, 1], [1931, 7, 1], [1932, 9, 1], [1932, 12, 1], [1933, 3, 1], [1933, 11, 1], [1934, 5, 1], [1935, 1, 1], [1935, 4, 1], [1935, 7, 1], [1936, 9, 1], [1936, 12, 1], [1937, 3, 1], [1937, 11, 1], [1938, 5, 1], [1939, 1, 1], [1939, 4, 1], [1939, 7, 1], [1940, 9, 1], [1940, 12, 1], [1941, 3, 1], [1941, 11, 1], [1942, 5, 1], [1943, 1, 1], [1943, 4, 1], [1943, 7, 1], [1944, 9, 1], [1944, 12, 1], [1945, 3, 1], [1945, 11, 1], [1946, 5, 1], [1947, 1, 1], [1947, 4, 1], [1947, 7, 1], [1948, 9, 1], [1948, 12, 1], [1949, 3, 1], [1949, 11, 1], [1950, 5, 1], [1951, 1, 1], [1951, 4, 1], [1951, 7, 1], [1952, 9, 1], [1952, 12, 1], [1953, 3, 1], [1953, 11, 1], [1954, 5, 1], [1955, 1, 1], [1955, 4, 1], [1955, 7, 1], [1956, 9, 1], [1956, 12, 1], [1957, 3, 1], [1957, 11, 1], [1958, 5, 1], [1959, 1, 1], [1959, 4, 1], [1959, 7, 1], [1960, 9, 1], [1960, 12, 1], [1961, 3, 1], [1961, 11, 1], [1962, 5, 1], [1963, 1, 1], [1963, 4, 1], [1963, 7, 1], [1964, 9, 1], [1964, 12, 1], [1965, 3, 1], [1965, 11, 1], [1966, 5, 1], [1967, 1, 1], [1967, 4, 1], [1967, 7, 1], [1968, 9, 1], [1968, 12, 1], [1969, 3, 1], [1969, 11, 1], [1970, 5, 1], [1971, 1, 1], [1971, 4, 1], [1971, 7, 1], [1972, 9, 1], [1972, 12, 1], [1973, 3, 1], [1973, 11, 1], [1974, 5, 1], [1975, 1, 1], [1975, 4, 1], [1975, 7, 1], [1976, 9, 1], [1976, 12, 1], [1977, 3, 1], [1977, 11, 1], [1978, 5, 1], [1979, 1, 1], [1979, 4, 1], [1979, 7, 1], [1980, 9, 1], [1980, 12, 1], [1981, 3, 1], [1981, 11, 1], [1982, 5, 1], [1983, 1, 1], [1983, 4, 1], [1983, 7, 1], [1984, 9, 1], [1984, 12, 1], [1985, 3, 1], [1985, 11, 1], [1986, 5, 1], [1987, 1, 1], [1987, 4, 1], [1987, 7, 1], [1988, 9, 1], [1988, 12, 1], [1989, 3, 1], [1989, 11, 1], [1990, 5, 1], [1991, 1, 1], [1991, 4, 1], [1991, 7, 1], [1992, 9, 1], [1992, 12, 1], [1993, 3, 1], [1993, 11, 1], [1994, 5, 1], [1995, 1, 1], [1995, 4, 1], [1995, 7, 1], [1996, 9, 1], [1996, 12, 1], [1997, 3, 1], [1997, 11, 1], [1998, 5, 1], [1999, 1, 1], [1999, 4, 1], [1999, 7, 1], [2000, 9, 1], [2000, 12, 1]]
```

I'm not sure what I have done wrong.

Comment: You can use the `datetime` module to make this problem much easier

Comment: I discovered that once I went to look for the real solution.  I don't want this hanging over my head though.  :)

Comment: You got your answer - but also look at `dateutil` :)

Comment: Use calendar.Calendar(). Its a one liner after importing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using modulus incorrectly. Try:

```
if year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0):
```

Comment: Thanks.  I should have noticed this.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought I would like to share my code for this question in the hope it might help someone or better yet someone might want to critique it.

I am aware there is a lot of printing or what some might think unnecessary printing going on, it helps me understand the console, so please save your breath if you are going to comment about this.

```
public class CountingSundays 
{
    enum days {Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday,     Wednesday};

    private int totalNumberDays, // help to carry the days
                daysOfCurrentMonth, // check day of month
                month, // track month
                year, // track year
                firstSundays; // count the number of first sundays

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        // create an instance of CountingSundays
        CountingSundays cs = new CountingSundays();

        cs.year = 1901; // set the year
        cs.totalNumberDays = 1; // set the day

        while(cs.year < 2001)
        {
            // beginning of the year
            cs.month = 1; // reset the months

            // 30 days, Sept, April, June, Nov
            // 31 days, Jan, Mar, May, Jul, Aug, Oct, Dec
            // year % 4 == 0 and not 2000 as 2000 % 400 == 0,
            // feb is 29, else its 28

            while(cs.month < 13)
            {
                // beginning a new month
                cs.daysOfCurrentMonth = 1;
                // track the number of days per month
                int monthlyDayCutOff = 1; 

                if( cs.month == 4 | // Apr
                    cs.month == 6 | // Jun
                    cs.month == 9 | // Sep
                    cs.month == 11 ) // Nov

                         monthlyDayCutOff = 30; // these months have 30
                // if
                else if(cs.month == 2)
                {
                    // this is feb, check if it is a leap year
                    if(cs.year % 4 == 0 && 
                       cs.year % 100 != 0 ||
                       cs.year % 400 == 0)

                        monthlyDayCutOff = 29; // leap year

                    else
                        monthlyDayCutOff = 28; // not a leap year
                } // else if

                else

                    monthlyDayCutOff = 31; // one of the remaining months
                // else
                // use a while loop to calculate the days
                while(cs.daysOfCurrentMonth < monthlyDayCutOff)
                {
                    if(cs.daysOfCurrentMonth == 1 &
                       days.values()[cs.totalNumberDays % 7] == days.Sunday)
                    {
                        cs.firstSundays++; // increment first sundays
                        System.out.println("There is a first sunday in " + 
                                cs.month);

                    } // if

                    // print current month date, and day
                    // the modulus helps cycle thru our enum
                    System.out.println(cs.daysOfCurrentMonth + " " + 
                    days.values()[cs.totalNumberDays % 7]);

                    // print some statements
                    cs.daysOfCurrentMonth++; // increment days of month
                    cs.totalNumberDays++; // increment the total number of days

                } // while days

                // end of month
                cs.month++;

                System.out.println("\n\n" + cs.month);
            } // while month

            cs.year++;
        } // while year

        cs.year++;
        // print money shot
        System.out.println("Num of 1st sundays: " + cs.firstSundays);
    } // main

} // CountingSundays
```